# Convert a complex SQL query to PANDAS dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Please help me to implement below complex query in PANDAS Dataframe.
I'm trying to implement this logic on server side rather than calling from stored procedure.

Data looks like below. I have table1 of 100,000(vary) rows and table2 of fixed 12 rows.

Ex: **Table1**

| parentkey | childkey | datetime | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | AD12 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 950 |
| 578 | AB3U | 2021-09-02 18:56:23.000 | 647 |
| 324 | AD12 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 960 |
| 324 | AD12 | 2021-08-13 15:30:00.000 | 950 |

Ex: **Table2**

| startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-08-26 | 2021-09-02 |
| 2021-08-19 | 2021-08-26 |
| 2021-08-12 | 2021-08-19 |
| 2021-08-05 | 2021-08-12 |

**Expected Output**

| datetime | parentkey | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-19 | 324 | 950 |
| 2021-08-26 | 578 | 647 |

SQL query:

```
Select date, 
parentkey,
group_id
from (Table2) c
cross apply ( 
   select date = c.startdate,
          latest.parentkey,
          latest.group_id 
   from ( select r.parentkey, 
                 r.group_id,
                 RN = ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY r.parentkey,r.childkey ORDER BY r.[datetime] 
                      DESC )
           from Table1) r
           where r.[datetime] <= c.enddate
    )latest
    where latest.RN = 1
) r
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Query explanation:

Table2 contains startdate, enddate of work weeks. Table1 contains actual data.

1. Apply cross join on Table1 and Table2.
2. 1st innermost query: Get the RowNumber for the Table1 uisng parentkey, childkey and order by datetime.
3. 2nd subquery: Change the Table1[datetime] to Table2[startdate] if the Table1[datetime] <= Table2[enddate]
4. 3rd sub query: Give results whose RowNumber is equal to 1

Comment: Please [edit] to include your expected output to make a [mcve] since we can't run your query against your server

Comment: Can you describe what your query does and share your expected output?

Comment: Added expected output.

Comment: Table2 contains startdate, enddate of work weeks. Table1 contains actual data. 
My query:
Apply cross join to Table1 and Table2
1st innermost query: 
get the RowNumber for the Table1 uisng parentkey, childkey and order by datetime.
2nd subquery:
change the Table1[datetime] to Table2[startdate] if the Table1[datetime] <= Table2[enddate]
3rd sub query:
give results whose RowNumber is equal to 1